# How can i create a program in C that records terminal outputs into a text file?

Tags: c

I work with a terminal and often i have to do it fast. Sometimes, rarely, i need to prove a point by looking at a terminal output from yesterday, for example.

I need my terminal entries to be saved in a text file and instead of copying and pasting the terminal output with my mouse, i want to practice C a bit (since apparently, i haven't done it much)

Long story, short: I want my terminal output to be saved into a text file in the most automated way possible.

Comment: On Unix-like systems there’s the `tee` command, which, when used together with shell redirections, allows you to see and save the standard output to files at the same time.

Comment: I think that your question is a little confusing, Do you want a program that reads the terminal history running all commands inside it and saves it to a file?

Comment: @kotatsuyaki great. I didn't know that. I'll look it up, however i still want to write a program in C:)

Comment: @jvx8ss i want the terminal output to be saved to a file. If i write "ping google.com" i want everything after i hit enter to be recorded.

Thank you for being here:)

Comment: You could do this by popping open a shell, capturing STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, and just forwarding those. It'll take deliberate launching though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [screen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) utility (if you're using a supported operating system).

In order to log terminal output, you have to do something like what `screen` does, which is not possible to do in a portable fashion: create a monitor which sits between the terminal session and the terminal itself. In Unix-like systems, you can do that with a [pseudoterminal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html). However, since a terminal is much more than a simple linear stream of characters -- it also supports arbitrary cursor movements, as well as recolouring and other style changes --, the log of the output also need to include console control codes. That makes it possible to replay the log, but it is not so easy to use it as a simple text file; additional work would have to be done in order to make that possible.

Comment: Screen and Tee seem like cool solutions. I just tried Tee (Recommended by @kotatsuyaki), but i still want to practice some C programming. Solutions such as "tee" might take time, because although it's easier than programming software in C, it takes longer to use it.

Comment: Tee is a good example, it's commonly used "just" to copy `stdin` to the given file and `stdout`. You could implement it as simple as possible, with error handling a 10-liner or so.

Comment: Thank you for your participation. I wish you a pleasant evening.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting and cool solution:

```
$ script file.log 
$ commands and whatnot 
$ exit
```

This saves a log file with all the command outputs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple program that reads a command and prints to `stdout` using `popen`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s cmd\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = popen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
        return 1;

    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, stdout);

    pclose(fp);
}
```

```bash
$ gcc main.c
$ ./a.out "ls"
a.out
main.c
```

If you want to save it to a different file, just change `fputc(c, stdout)` with your `FILE*`

Comment: Note that if you want to run a command with multiple flags, that's how you do it: `./a.out "ls -l"`